# Accessing ruby elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, element

Can someone explain to me why arr[-3] #=>4 and arr[2,3] #=> [3,4,5]? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Images of text are discouraged here. Please just copy/paste the text itself.

Comment: This is clearly explained in the Ruby online documentation.  Why didn't you read it before grabbing the screenshot?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help?

Comment: It's a great idea to get in the habit of reading [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements). Your question is clearly answered in the paragraph preceding the example code you copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr[-1]` gives you the last element of `arr`, `arr[-2]` the second-to-last element and so on.

`arr[2, 3]` gives you from the element at index 2, three elements of `arr`

`arr[2..3]` gives you from the element at index 2 to the element at index 3

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hey, my pleasure :)